# Implementing a deadlock detection algorithm; issue with the loops

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, process, deadlock

I have been looking for the past 3 hours, and I can't find the problem with this code. The user inputs the number of processes and the number of types of resources and the algorithm determines if there is a deadlock or not. I am certain that the problem is in the stepTwo() method as I have checked everything in the first block of code, and it was all fine.

Here is the pseudocode: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt9cvk5h3ij7wqz/deadlockdetection.jpg?dl=0

Here is main, variables, etc.:

```
public class AssignmentIII
{       
public static int numProcesses; // Represents the number of processes
public static int numResources; // Represents the number of different types of resources

public static int[] available; // Create matrix for available processes
public static int[][] allocation; // Create allocation matrix
public static int[][] request; // Create request matrix
public static int[] work; // Create work matrix
public static Boolean[] finish; // Create finish matrix

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("input3.txt")); // Create file scanner

        System.out.println("Please enter the total number of processes: ");
        numProcesses = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of different types of resources: ");
        numResources = scan.nextInt();

        // Initalize matrices sizes
        available = new int[numResources];
        allocation = new int[numProcesses][numResources];
        request = new int[numProcesses][numResources];
        work = new int[numResources];
        finish = new Boolean[numProcesses];

        // Initialize the available matrix contents
        for(int i = 0; i < numResources; i++)
        available[i]=fileScan.nextInt();

        // Initialize the allocation matrix contents
        for(int j = 0; j < numProcesses; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < numResources; k++)
                allocation[j][k]=fileScan.nextInt();

        // Initialize the request matrix contents
        for(int m = 0; m < numProcesses; m++)
            for(int n = 0; n < numResources; n++)
                request[m][n]=fileScan.nextInt();

        // Begin deadlock detection algorithm               
        for(int i = 0; i < numResources; i++) // Intialize Work := Available
            work[i]=available[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < numProcesses; j++) // Check for Allocation != 0 and initialize Finish accordingly
        {
            // the Allocation matrix = 0 if the sum of all its elements = 0
            // which is the same as if every element were = 0
            int sumAllocation = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < numResources; i++)
            {
                sumAllocation += allocation[j][i];
            }

            if (sumAllocation != 0)
                finish[j] = false;
            else finish[j] = true;
        }

        stepTwo();

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        System.out.println("An error has occured. The file cannot be found.");
        }
}
```

The error is occurring somewhere in here, but I can't figure it out:

```
    public static void stepTwo()
{
    // Step 2: Find an index j where Finish[j] = false & Request[j] <= Work
    for(int j = 0; j < numProcesses; j++)
    {
        if (finish[j] == true && j == numProcesses)
            {
                System.out.println("No deadlocks.");
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < numResources; i++)
        {
            if (request[j][i] <= work[i] && finish[j] == false)
            {
                if (i == (numResources-1))
                {
                    finish[j] = true;

                    for(int m = 0; m < numResources; m++)
                    {
                        work[m] += allocation[j][m];
                    }

                    j = -1; // Reset counter

                    break;
                }
            }

            else if (request[j][i] > work[i] && finish[j] == false)
            {
                System.out.println("P" + j + " is deadlocked.");
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

My input is:

0 0 0

0 1 0

2 0 0

3 0 3

2 1 1

0 0 2

0 0 0

2 0 2

0 0 0

1 0 0

0 0 2

The output I get is:

P1 is deadlocked.
P1 is deadlocked.

The correct output should be "No deadlocks."

Any help would be appreciated.